# Visual studio community edition 16.8.4 removed Merge From not showig

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Visual studio 2019 Community edition..
Can't find 'Merge From' item in the manage branches window in vs 16.8.4.
Has it been removed?
[image]

[image]

Comment: are you sure this is vs2019?

Comment: Yes! the latest update

Comment: can you show about window at least

Comment: So, this is not normal VS2019. This is community edition. I doubt, you get your answer here. Why not ask microsoft?